# Gauge Chart change colorset with javascript

Tags: javascript, visualforce-charting

I want to change dynamically the colorset of my Gauge Chart. I tried to use the property "rendererFn" but  nothing happened, the color didn't change.

**Apex Page :**

```
<apex:chart data="{!data}" height="180" width="250" renderTo="chart_{!data}" name="MyChart" animate="true"> 
    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="top" minimum="0" maximum="150" margin="-1"/>
    <apex:gaugeSeries labelField="label" dataField="impact_total" tips="true" donut="60" highlight="false" rendererFn="ChangeColor"/>
</apex:chart>



<script>
 function changeColor(klass, item){    this.colorSet = ["#FF0000","#ddd"];}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is cased sensitive but you have ChangeColor and changeColor. Check your browser's JavaScript console for this error and other errors.